# C# linq increment variable inside anonymous select

Tags: c#, linq

In linq is it posible to increment variable inside anonymous select?

For example this is my code :

```
   int[] coefficients = { 1, 2, 3, };
   int i = 0;

   var verbalResult =
                  from fq in finishedQuizzes
                  from vq in fq.Quiz.VerbalQuizes
                  group vq by vq.Question.ExamTagId into r
                  select new
                  {
                      Tag = r.First().Question.ExamTag.Name,                 
                      CorrectAnswerCount = r.Sum(e => e.ISMovedAnswerCorrect ? 1 : 0),
                      questionCount = r.Count(),
                      coefficient = coefficients[i],
                      i++
                  };
```

I want to get coefficient by index(i). Can I increment the `i` variable like this?

Comment: Have you tried it?

Comment: Why not just do `i = verbalResult.Count()`?

Comment: But i want to dynamically get coefficient by index

Comment: Is this querying hitting the database, or in memory?

Comment: I am converting finishedQuizzes toList

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No this is not possible. But there exists two solutions. Either you increment `i` in the indexer.

```
[...]
coefficient = coefficients[i++],
[...]
```

or you use the indexer:

```
var verbalResult = .... into r select r;
var result = verbalResult.Select((item,index) =>{ new { Tag = ... } /* index is the current position */}
```

> Be aware of IndexOutOfRangeException when `i` or `index` exceeds `coefficients.Length`

Answer (score 8):

There are times when LINQ (the language bits) aren't as helpful as the actual library methods available. If you stick to the extension methods, there is an overload of `Select` that *hands you* the index. So... everything you want.

Basically:

```
.Select((x, i) => {...})
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534869(v=vs.100).aspx